# Extracting string parts from data

Tags: xslt, xpath

Need to extra part of a string. Assume I can access "date" and get on the output 
21.01.2013
Now I don't want to have the '.2013'. I tried these lines:

```
<xsl:value-of select="date"/>  

<xsl:variable name="bdate">  
    <xsl:value-of select="date"/>  
</xsl:variable>  

<p>Birthday: <xsl:copy-of substring($bdate,1,5) /></p><br/>
```

The first line only works, with all lines any variations of the last line will always throw an error. But there is a solution for it, I'm sure. Can anyone help for it .. how would last line look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($bdate,1,5)" />
```

Should work (XSLT has to be well formed XML)